# Where can I find documentation for Ember nearestOfType() function

Tags: ember.js

I've searched through Google, etc. and can not find more than a cursory reference. What does this function do?

I am trying to figure out how the ember-bootstrap add-on works, and came upon this function here: https://github.com/kaliber5/ember-bootstrap/blob/master/addon/mixins/component-child.js#L31

I think I know what the code is doing, I've just never seen this `nearestOfType()` function before.

Answer (score 3):

Found my answer on my own by looking in Ember's repo. Apparently this function is private and is deprecated with contextual components as the replacement:

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/02d36cb1e09823b47740aea30ba372592c5e55e9/packages/ember-views/lib/mixins/view_support.js#L33